# Hyphenating a Hyphenated word: tree-trunk-like legs

Tags: spelling, hyphens

> He seemed to have tree-trunk-like legs.

How do you hyphenate a hyphenated word, properly, and grammatically?

Comment: *tree-trunk-like legs*, but  *legs like tree-trunks* would be more natural.

Comment: That's an example of **he-who-must-not-be-named**.

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a lot of variation on this point.

"Tree trunk" is *usually* written with a space ("tree trunk"). <sub>[[link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tree+trunk%2Ctree-trunk%2Ctreetrunk&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctree%20trunk%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctree%20-%20trunk%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctreetrunk%3B%2Cc0)]</sub>  The suffix "–like" can be written either solid (e.g. "trunklike") or with a hyphen (e.g. "trunk-like"). <sub>[[link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=trunklike%2Ctrunk-like&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctrunklike%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctrunk%20-%20like%3B%2Cc0)]</sub>  So I wouldn't be surprised to see either of these:

1. tree trunklike legs
2. tree trunk-like legs

But when a compound noun precedes and modifies another noun, it's often hyphenated, even if the compound noun is otherwise usually written with a space. Obviously "tree trunk[-]like" isn't a compound noun, but "tree trunk" *is*, and the phrase as a whole precedes and modifies *legs*, so I also wouldn't be surprised to see either of these:

3. tree-trunklike legs
4. tree-trunk-like legs

What makes your case especially tricky is that grammatically, it parses as {{tree trunk}like} rather than as {tree {trunklike}}, so #1–3 above are all a bit awkward in that they make it look like the "–like" attaches only to the "trunk". Many people will address that by choosing #4, but the more typographically savvy may also address it by separating the "–like" with an [en dash](http://grammarist.com/grammar/en-dash/), which is much like a hyphen except that it's physically a bit longer and indicates a somewhat greater separation. So I also wouldn't be surprised to see either of these:

5. tree trunk–like legs
6. tree-trunk–like legs

Personally, I would probably go with #6, but I think either #4 or #5 would also be fine.

---

That said, for your specific sentence, I wouldn't recommend this phrasing anyway; I find it much more natural to say "He seemed to have legs like tree trunks". For that matter, I would probably drop the "seemed" — I don't think it adds anything — and just say "He had legs like tree trunks", or "His legs were like tree trunks."

I'd only suggest the "tree-trunk–like" approach if something more were being said *about* the tree-trunk–like legs:

> His tree-trunk–like legs betrayed his Entish origin.

Comment: I think, yes. Indeed. I think I had seen something about a, maybe, en-dash.